# Possible to make One MySQL TRANSACTION with Record Locking by separate AJAX queries / HTML SUBSESSIONS?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session

I'd like to make a multi user Webcilent+PHP+MySQL(InnoDB) Record Locking and Updateing process in two steps (AJAX POST) but I can't found solution.

What I want to do:

1. When I click on the data in the web client grid lock the selected record for update (by AJAX XMLHttpRequest - POST *[First]*)
   *(To avoid make lost updates. For example by concurrent clients same time edits on not surely actual datas and/or concurrent client sooner update than the first)*

**START TRANSACTION;**

**SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;**

2. Edit the data in the Web Client and UPDATE the SQL Field with the new value (by AJAX XMLHttpRequest - POST *[Second]*)

**UPDATE ...;**

**COMMIT;**

The problem:

The two step is necessary becouse I want to deny for the second client to start edit the data if the other (first) client edit is in progress. (started but not finished)

But it seem not to be possible to make MySQL to not COMMIT the TRANSACTION before the end of whole TRANSACTION (after UPDATE as I want) becouse the PHP connection closed each time when the actual PHP script (AJAX Post Handler Process) ended.

I already tryed all the wrong way to keep the connection between the Client (through PHP) and MySQL alive: by storing it $_SESSION PHP varaible and use Presistent Connetion but it not work. And then I found in PHP manual why not. But what I don't find is the solution.

Anyway possible it make with HTML+PHP+SQL make what I want?
And if yes how?
And MySQL how to know which client send the querys? (If may turn off AUTO COMMIT help)

(The UPDATE work correctly so the "only" problem is the missing locking.)

Thanks for Answers!

Comment: Have you considered adding your own fields to the table to indicate that the row is locked and cannot be edited? That would probably be the easiest way to accomplish what you want, though it does not involve using the MySQL engine to maintain transaction state.

Comment: Hi! Someone else suggest me too to do this. And I think I would be able to do this with use the clients $_SESSION SID-s but I don't want to do this becouse later I want use this updating method on SQL WIEVs - wich based on more underlaying TBALES (if I know well this possible in MySQL too) - and this situation I think it is become wery difficult to identify the underlaying table datas (records) through SQL triggers...